# Get CKEditor content? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

My CKEditor code is

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( \'big_info\' );
    CKEDITOR.config.height = \'330px\';
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Full =
    [
        [\'Source\',\'-\',\'Templates\'],
        [\'Maximize\', \'ShowBlocks\'],
        [\'Cut\',\'Copy\',\'Paste\',\'PasteText\',\'PasteFromWord\',\'-\',\'SpellChecker\', \'Scayt\'],
        [\'Undo\',\'Redo\',\'-\',\'Find\',\'Replace\',\'-\',\'SelectAll\',\'RemoveFormat\'],
        [\'TextColor\',\'BGColor\'],

        [\'NumberedList\',\'BulletedList\',\'-\',\'Outdent\',\'Indent\',\'Blockquote\'],
        \'/\',
        [\'Bold\',\'Italic\',\'Underline\',\'Strike\',\'-\'],
        [\'Styles\',\'Format\',\'Font\',\'FontSize\'],
        [\'JustifyLeft\',\'JustifyCenter\',\'JustifyRight\',\'JustifyBlock\'],
        [\'Link\',\'Unlink\',\'Anchor\'],
        [\'Image\',\'Flash\',\'Table\',\'HorizontalRule\',\'PageBreak\']
    ];

    CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( editor, { BasePath : \'/javascript/ckfinder/\', RememberLastFolder : false } ) ;
};
```

I want to take the content of the edit box and send it via JSON from my jQuery script. I can't find how do to it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is explained in the [integration Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration)

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.big_info.getData();
```

You can use also the jQuery integration as explained in the [CKEditor blog](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) and [jQuery integration docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)

```
// Get the editor data.
var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
// Set the editor data.
$( 'textarea.editor' ).val( 'my new content' );
```