# get innerhtml textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, textarea

on site [sample question](http://iranfairco.com/example/innerhtml.aspx)

HTML

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="clk();" id="btn"/>
```

this text area is a ckeditor
SCRIPT

```
 function clk()
   {
    alert($("#txt").html());
    alert($("#txt").val());
    alert($("#txt").text());
 //   alert($("#txt").innerhtml());

   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
               editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'txt',{language : 'en',on :{}} );

   });
```

this code alert ' ' how can get innerhtml `txt`??
 on site [smaple question](http://iranfairco.com/example/innerhtml.aspx)

**Edit**

when edit `txt` and click on `btn` then `val()` alert' '

Comment: Use the CKEditor jQuery Adapter. Then `val` will work. Read this: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textarea is replaced by an iframe ( in a textarea I don't think you can put image ).

This seems to be an answer about how to get content from cke iframe : [Get CKEditor content? - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826036/get-ckeditor-content-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will alert something if you have anything in the textarea. Since it is an input element it will have value property so just use val() method.

```
$("#txt").val();
```

Comment: Can you try this `$("#txt").val("testData")` and `alert($("#txt").val())`? what do you get?

Comment: this show testdata but i want that when user edit text and click on btn alert which taht edit

Comment: If user enters something in the textarea it will definitely alert that. You can make a null or empty check before you alert. Use $.trim() method to trim the value in case there are spaces in the start or end of the value

Answer (score 0):

you have to use getData() to get the innerhtml from CKEditor

[click here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#txt).val();` works only for simple textarea. And you want to text CKEditor-textarea. See here stackoverflow.com/questions/4826036/get-ckeditor-content-jquery. Looks like your question is related to it.

Answer (score 0):

to get inner text of textarea like .html() method you can use this code to replace \n with

```
$("#txt").val().replace('\n',"<br />");
```